# How to get Facebook friendList?

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

I am developing a Android chat app with facebook login and I want to get the user's all faccebook friends, either they are using this app or not. But the returned list is only contain the friends who are using the app. SO would any one like to give me a direction that how can I access the all user's friends. I also searched for the desired result but all my efforts proved futile. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have reason to believe Facebook will allow this at all?  Facebook may consider this against their app policies.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _I also searched for the desired result but all my efforts proved futile_? Please tell exactly what you have tried, so people won't have to try the same thing.

Comment: @Keppil   I mean to say that I also searched for the result what I want. For example,  I searched for how can I access my friends who have installed or have not installed my app as well. So not found desired result.

Comment: @LouisWasserman so there will be definately some way to allow this.

Answer (score 1):

according to new sdk facebook returns the person's friends who also use the app.

If you want to access a list of non-app-using friends, there are two options:

1. If you want to let your people tag their friends in stories that they publish to Facebook using your App, you can use the /me/taggable_friends API. Use of this endpoint requires review by Facebook and should only be used for the case where you're rendering a list of friends in order to let the user tag them in a post.
2. If your App is a Game AND your Game supports Facebook Canvas, you can use the /me/invitable_friends endpoint in order to render a custom invite dialog, then pass the tokens returned by this API to the standard Requests Dialog.